Strange Error message in device manager
After i tried to install the drivers for audio card (EMU APS), i received in the device manager and for the mentioned card, this message :
"EMU PnP bus compensator entry - remove me"
It is not exactly a message. It is the title of the device in the device manager under the sound cards. Instead of saying "EMU APS 10K audio processor " say ""EMU PnP bus compensator entry - remove me""
It happens right after i tried to install the drivers in safe mode. I tried in safe mode because in normal mode, after the installation i received (in device manager) the error code 3 (the drivers are bad OR there is a problem with memory).
Before some years i managed to install this audio card in WinXP, with drivers i found in the WEB, but after a failure of the card (detected by Windows but did not have sound) i tried every Win OS for which i had drivers, but no luck. So now i decide to install it on the native for it OS, the Win98 ,but no luck again
I do not have the original installation CD-ROM.
I also take care the hardware option, and replaced on it many components (capacitors, voltage regulators, amplifiers, volume control, resistances). I am not a electronic professional and i have not the background to tell if the card is broken. I just replace some components that maybe cause the problem. Also i cannot find the schematic.

Problem solved. Replace a PLD on the card.
